# Synonyms for local-government tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I was asking a new [question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34412/what-could-a-vegan-mayor-actually-do) about [local-government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-government) but I'm new to the site and that wasn't the first term that came to mind. First I looked for tags like [civic](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civic) or [municipal](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/municipal) but found nothing at all. Could we add those as synonyms for local-government? That would make it so much easier to find!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that civic is a synonym for local government.  Civic participation does not need to be locally focused.

I would recognize municipal more easily than local government as well.

---

Another possibility would be something like [civic-elections-canada](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civic-elections-canada) and [municipal-government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/municipal-government).  That would be clear that civic elections has a specific meaning in Canada and when someone types civic or municipal, they'd see [local-government](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-government).  I would kind of prefer [civic-government-canada](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/civic-government-canada), but if that's not how the term is used...

Comment: Interesting. In Canada, municipal elections are commonly known as civic elections. But we never use the word "civic" when referring to provincial or federal elections.

Comment: @Nic  Do you refer to civic government as well?  Or just elections?

Comment: Mostly just in the context of elections

Comment: I added two new tags and started the synonym process.  Not sure how many people have sufficient answer score on local-government to vote.  It might require moderator action to finish.

Comment: Update, since Community has dug this question up again: Both synonyms have been accepted.